# Maximizing quadratic functions with part of the vector fixed

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadratic-forms

The problem is 
\begin{eqnarray}
\max_\mathbf{x} \,&& \frac{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{R}\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{x}}, \\
\textrm{s.t.,} && \mathbf{x}(1:s) = \mathbf{d},
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mathbf{x}$ is a complex-valued vector of dimension $N$, $\mathbf{R}$ is a positive definite Hermitian matrix. The constraint means that the first $s$ entries of the vector $\mathbf{x}$ is fixed to be $\mathbf{d}$.

I understand that without the constraint, the solution is the dominant eigenvector of $\mathbf{R}$. Then how about with the constraint? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $\rm x := (x_1, x_2) = (d, x_2)$ and solve the *unconstrained* optimization problem in $\rm x_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Following your approach, do you know if the unconstrained problem has a closed-form solution?

Comment: Do you really need a closed-form solution? Won't a numerical one be enough?

Comment: I think a closed-form solution is always preferred. Anyway, just out of curiousity, is it possible to have a closed-form solution to this problem?